# How to query all files attached to the Opportunity

Tags: soql, files

I know how to query all the attachments related to the opportunity, but how to do the same for **files** attached. Seems like a file is a part of a content library.

Comment: Are these chatter files? If so, [this related question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/564/how-to-query-all-chatter-files-attached-to-a-record) should provide a solution for you.

Comment: No, I'm asking about Files. You can attach files using Lightning experience

Comment: Solved. The file is actually a content document and could be easily obtained via foreign key: SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = '<Opportunity or other object id here>'

Comment: Can you add your comment as an answer and mark it as best answer, as it might help other users in the future with the same question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solved. The file is actually a content document and could be easily obtained via foreign key:

```
SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = '<Opportunity or other object id here>'
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ContentDocumentId, linkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = "123"

ContentDocumentId = a salesforce object Id where this file is being used
, linkedEntityId = id of the stored file

Comment: How is that different from accepted answer?

Comment: the query is the same. Just aadded the info about ContentDocumentId and linkedEntityId